# Mariadb Crashes Occasionally on filesort

Tags: mysql, crash, mariadb, out-of-memory

Have an app that's been running for a couple years without issue. Suddenly, we've started seeing Mariadb crash and recover during various queries that seem to typically have the filesort function running on them. We do a lot of complex queries and sometimes are forced to sort on a calculated field. These previously worked without issue, so I'm not convinced the queries themselves are at fault.

I'm not sure of this is a configuration issue or if it's a bug or hardware issue. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Server has 16GB of ram with 6 CPUs.

Log files are as follows:

```
Version: '10.2.24-MariaDB-log'  socket: '/mnt/volume-01-part1/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
2019-06-27 12:52:23 139999433680640 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` not found.
190627 12:53:18 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.2.24-MariaDB-log
key_buffer_size=10485760
read_buffer_size=2097152
max_used_connections=9
max_threads=102
thread_count=16
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 430185 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7f53b80009a8
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x7f54287d1d30 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x56288037858e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x30d)[0x56287fe0421d]
sigaction.c:0(__restore_rt)[0x7f576a7ca5d0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z8filesortP3THDP5TABLEP8FilesortP16Filesort_trackerP4JOINy+0x2b4)[0x56287fe02684]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z17create_sort_indexP3THDP4JOINP13st_join_tableP8Filesort+0xd7)[0x56287fcb1b57]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN17Window_funcs_sort4execEP4JOINb+0x4a)[0x56287fd8ee2a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN24Window_funcs_computation4execEP4JOINb+0x2a)[0x56287fd8f53a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7AGGR_OP8end_sendEv+0xe7)[0x56287fcc20d7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24sub_select_postjoin_aggrP4JOINP13st_join_tableb+0x31)[0x56287fcc22a1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN10exec_innerEv+0x903)[0x56287fcc2bf3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x33)[0x56287fcc2f43]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_selectP3THDP10TABLE_LISTjR4ListI4ItemEPS4_jP8st_orderS9_S7_S9_yP13select_resultP18st_select_lex_unitP13st_select_lex+0x11a)[0x56287fcc309a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z18mysql_derived_fillP3THDP3LEXP10TABLE_LIST+0x152)[0x56287fc4ae62]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z27mysql_handle_single_derivedP3LEXP10TABLE_LISTj+0xe4)[0x56287fc4abd4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN13st_join_table12preread_initEv+0xdf)[0x56287fca2fbf]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10sub_selectP4JOINP13st_join_tableb+0x2f8)[0x56287fca32c8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN10exec_innerEv+0xa3f)[0x56287fcc2d2f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0x33)[0x56287fcc2f43]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_selectP3THDP10TABLE_LISTjR4ListI4ItemEPS4_jP8st_orderS9_S7_S9_yP13select_resultP18st_select_lex_unitP13st_select_lex+0x11a)[0x56287fcc309a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13handle_selectP3THDP3LEXP13select_resultm+0x254)[0x56287fcc3bf4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x41c4ef)[0x56287fba74ef]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x334d)[0x56287fc6e99d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_statebb+0x2de)[0x56287fc748ee]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcjbb+0x21f5)[0x56287fc77ac5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x165)[0x56287fc786e5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP7CONNECT+0x1aa)[0x56287fd41e3a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x3d)[0x56287fd41f5d]
pthread_create.c:0(start_thread)[0x7f576a7c2dd5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f5768b64ead]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0x7f53b800f130): [REMOVED]
Connection ID (thread ID): 31
Status: NOT_KILLED

Optimizer switch: index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file...
Working directory at /mnt/volume-01-part1/mysql
Resource Limits:
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             63458                63458                processes 
Max open files            16364                16364                files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       63458                63458                signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us        
Core pattern: core
```

Server variables are:

```
'aria_block_size', '8192'
'aria_checkpoint_interval', '30'
'aria_checkpoint_log_activity', '1048576'
'aria_encrypt_tables', 'OFF'
'aria_force_start_after_recovery_failures', '0'
'aria_group_commit', 'none'
'aria_group_commit_interval', '0'
'aria_log_file_size', '1073741824'
'aria_log_purge_type', 'immediate'
'aria_max_sort_file_size', '9223372036853727232'
'aria_page_checksum', 'ON'
'aria_pagecache_age_threshold', '300'
'aria_pagecache_buffer_size', '134217728'
'aria_pagecache_division_limit', '100'
'aria_pagecache_file_hash_size', '512'
'aria_recover_options', 'BACKUP,QUICK'
'aria_repair_threads', '1'
'aria_sort_buffer_size', '268434432'
'aria_stats_method', 'nulls_unequal'
'aria_sync_log_dir', 'NEWFILE'
'aria_used_for_temp_tables', 'ON'
'auto_increment_increment', '1'
'auto_increment_offset', '1'
'autocommit', 'ON'
'automatic_sp_privileges', 'ON'
'back_log', '50'
'basedir', '/usr/'
'big_tables', 'OFF'
'binlog_annotate_row_events', 'ON'
'binlog_cache_size', '31457280'
'binlog_checksum', 'CRC32'
'binlog_commit_wait_count', '0'
'binlog_commit_wait_usec', '100000'
'binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates', 'OFF'
'binlog_format', 'MIXED'
'binlog_optimize_thread_scheduling', 'ON'
'binlog_row_image', 'FULL'
'binlog_stmt_cache_size', '32768'
'bulk_insert_buffer_size', '8388608'
'character_set_client', 'utf8'
'character_set_connection', 'utf8'
'character_set_database', 'utf8'
'character_set_filesystem', 'binary'
'character_set_results', 'utf8'
'character_set_server', 'latin1'
'character_set_system', 'utf8'
'character_sets_dir', '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/'
'check_constraint_checks', 'ON'
'collation_connection', 'utf8_general_ci'
'collation_database', 'utf8_general_ci'
'collation_server', 'latin1_swedish_ci'
'completion_type', 'NO_CHAIN'
'concurrent_insert', 'AUTO'
'connect_timeout', '10'
'core_file', 'OFF'
'datadir', '/mnt/volume-01-part1/mysql/'
'date_format', '%Y-%m-%d'
'datetime_format', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'
'deadlock_search_depth_long', '15'
'deadlock_search_depth_short', '4'
'deadlock_timeout_long', '50000000'
'deadlock_timeout_short', '10000'
'debug_no_thread_alarm', 'OFF'
'default_master_connection', ''
'default_regex_flags', ''
'default_storage_engine', 'MyISAM'
'default_tmp_storage_engine', ''
'default_week_format', '0'
'delay_key_write', 'ON'
'delayed_insert_limit', '100'
'delayed_insert_timeout', '300'
'delayed_queue_size', '1000'
'div_precision_increment', '4'
'encrypt_binlog', 'OFF'
'encrypt_tmp_disk_tables', 'OFF'
'encrypt_tmp_files', 'OFF'
'enforce_storage_engine', ''
'eq_range_index_dive_limit', '0'
'error_count', '0'
'event_scheduler', 'OFF'
'expensive_subquery_limit', '100'
'expire_logs_days', '3'
'explicit_defaults_for_timestamp', 'OFF'
'external_user', ''
'extra_max_connections', '1'
'extra_port', '0'
'flush', 'OFF'
'flush_time', '0'
'foreign_key_checks', 'ON'
'ft_boolean_syntax', '+ -><()~*:\"\"&|'
'ft_max_word_len', '84'
'ft_min_word_len', '4'
'ft_query_expansion_limit', '20'
'ft_stopword_file', '(built-in)'
'general_log', 'OFF'
'general_log_file', 'dtd-db-01.log'
'group_concat_max_len', '1048576'
'gtid_binlog_pos', '0-1-11007595'
'gtid_binlog_state', '0-1-11007595'
'gtid_current_pos', '0-1-11007595'
'gtid_domain_id', '0'
'gtid_ignore_duplicates', 'OFF'
'gtid_seq_no', '0'
'gtid_slave_pos', ''
'gtid_strict_mode', 'OFF'
'have_compress', 'YES'
'have_crypt', 'YES'
'have_dynamic_loading', 'YES'
'have_geometry', 'YES'
'have_openssl', 'YES'
'have_profiling', 'YES'
'have_query_cache', 'YES'
'have_rtree_keys', 'YES'
'have_ssl', 'DISABLED'
'have_symlink', 'DISABLED'
'histogram_size', '0'
'histogram_type', 'SINGLE_PREC_HB'
'host_cache_size', '228'
'hostname', 'dtd-db-01'
'identity', '0'
'ignore_builtin_innodb', 'OFF'
'ignore_db_dirs', ''
'in_transaction', '0'
'init_connect', ''
'init_file', ''
'init_slave', ''
'innodb_adaptive_flushing', 'ON'
'innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm', '10.000000'
'innodb_adaptive_hash_index', 'ON'
'innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions', '8'
'innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts', '8'
'innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay', '150000'
'innodb_autoextend_increment', '64'
'innodb_autoinc_lock_mode', '1'
'innodb_background_scrub_data_check_interval', '3600'
'innodb_background_scrub_data_compressed', 'OFF'
'innodb_background_scrub_data_interval', '604800'
'innodb_background_scrub_data_uncompressed', 'OFF'
'innodb_buf_dump_status_frequency', '0'
'innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size', '134217728'
'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown', 'ON'
'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now', 'OFF'
'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct', '25'
'innodb_buffer_pool_filename', 'ib_buffer_pool'
'innodb_buffer_pool_instances', '6'
'innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort', 'OFF'
'innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup', 'ON'
'innodb_buffer_pool_load_now', 'OFF'
'innodb_buffer_pool_populate', 'OFF'
'innodb_buffer_pool_size', '12079595520'
'innodb_change_buffer_max_size', '25'
'innodb_change_buffering', 'all'
'innodb_checksum_algorithm', 'crc32'
'innodb_checksums', 'ON'
'innodb_cleaner_lsn_age_factor', 'DEPRECATED'
'innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled', 'OFF'
'innodb_commit_concurrency', '0'
'innodb_compression_algorithm', 'zlib'
'innodb_compression_default', 'OFF'
'innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct', '5'
'innodb_compression_level', '6'
'innodb_compression_pad_pct_max', '50'
'innodb_concurrency_tickets', '5000'
'innodb_corrupt_table_action', 'deprecated'
'innodb_data_file_path', 'ibdata1:10M:autoextend'
'innodb_data_home_dir', ''
'innodb_deadlock_detect', 'ON'
'innodb_default_encryption_key_id', '1'
'innodb_default_row_format', 'dynamic'
'innodb_defragment', 'ON'
'innodb_defragment_fill_factor', '0.900000'
'innodb_defragment_fill_factor_n_recs', '20'
'innodb_defragment_frequency', '40'
'innodb_defragment_n_pages', '7'
'innodb_defragment_stats_accuracy', '0'
'innodb_disable_sort_file_cache', 'OFF'
'innodb_disallow_writes', 'OFF'
'innodb_doublewrite', 'ON'
'innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm', 'DEPRECATED'
'innodb_encrypt_log', 'OFF'
'innodb_encrypt_tables', 'OFF'
'innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age', '1'
'innodb_encryption_rotation_iops', '100'
'innodb_encryption_threads', '0'
'innodb_fake_changes', 'OFF'
'innodb_fast_shutdown', '1'
'innodb_fatal_semaphore_wait_threshold', '600'
'innodb_file_format', 'Barracuda'
'innodb_file_format_check', 'ON'
'innodb_file_format_max', 'Barracuda'
'innodb_file_per_table', 'ON'
'innodb_fill_factor', '100'
'innodb_flush_log_at_timeout', '1'
'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit', '2'
'innodb_flush_method', 'O_DIRECT'
'innodb_flush_neighbors', '1'
'innodb_flush_sync', 'ON'
'innodb_flushing_avg_loops', '30'
'innodb_force_load_corrupted', 'OFF'
'innodb_force_primary_key', 'OFF'
'innodb_force_recovery', '0'
'innodb_foreground_preflush', 'DEPRECATED'
'innodb_ft_aux_table', ''
'innodb_ft_cache_size', '8000000'
'innodb_ft_enable_diag_print', 'OFF'
'innodb_ft_enable_stopword', 'ON'
'innodb_ft_max_token_size', '84'
'innodb_ft_min_token_size', '3'
'innodb_ft_num_word_optimize', '2000'
'innodb_ft_result_cache_limit', '2000000000'
'innodb_ft_server_stopword_table', ''
'innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree', '2'
'innodb_ft_total_cache_size', '640000000'
'innodb_ft_user_stopword_table', ''
'innodb_idle_flush_pct', '100'
'innodb_immediate_scrub_data_uncompressed', 'OFF'
'innodb_instrument_semaphores', 'OFF'
'innodb_io_capacity', '200'
'innodb_io_capacity_max', '2000'
'innodb_kill_idle_transaction', '0'
'innodb_large_prefix', 'ON'
'innodb_lock_schedule_algorithm', 'fcfs'
'innodb_lock_wait_timeout', '120'
'innodb_locking_fake_changes', 'OFF'
'innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog', 'OFF'
'innodb_log_arch_dir', ''
'innodb_log_arch_expire_sec', '0'
'innodb_log_archive', 'OFF'
'innodb_log_block_size', '0'
'innodb_log_buffer_size', '33554432'
'innodb_log_checksum_algorithm', 'DEPRECATED'
'innodb_log_checksums', 'ON'
'innodb_log_compressed_pages', 'ON'
'innodb_log_file_size', '3221225472'
'innodb_log_files_in_group', '3'
'innodb_log_group_home_dir', './'
'innodb_log_optimize_ddl', 'ON'
'innodb_log_write_ahead_size', '8192'
'innodb_lru_scan_depth', '512'
'innodb_max_bitmap_file_size', '0'
'innodb_max_changed_pages', '0'
'innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct', '90.000000'
'innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm', '0.000000'
'innodb_max_purge_lag', '0'
'innodb_max_purge_lag_delay', '0'
'innodb_max_undo_log_size', '10485760'
'innodb_mirrored_log_groups', '0'
'innodb_monitor_disable', ''
'innodb_monitor_enable', ''
'innodb_monitor_reset', ''
'innodb_monitor_reset_all', ''
'innodb_mtflush_threads', '8'
'innodb_old_blocks_pct', '37'
'innodb_old_blocks_time', '1000'
'innodb_online_alter_log_max_size', '134217728'
'innodb_open_files', '2048'
'innodb_optimize_fulltext_only', 'OFF'
'innodb_page_cleaners', '4'
'innodb_page_size', '16384'
'innodb_prefix_index_cluster_optimization', 'OFF'
'innodb_print_all_deadlocks', 'OFF'
'innodb_purge_batch_size', '300'
'innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency', '128'
'innodb_purge_threads', '4'
'innodb_random_read_ahead', 'OFF'
'innodb_read_ahead_threshold', '56'
'innodb_read_io_threads', '8'
'innodb_read_only', 'OFF'
'innodb_replication_delay', '0'
'innodb_rollback_on_timeout', 'OFF'
'innodb_rollback_segments', '128'
'innodb_safe_truncate', 'ON'
'innodb_sched_priority_cleaner', '0'
'innodb_scrub_log', 'OFF'
'innodb_scrub_log_speed', '256'
'innodb_show_locks_held', '0'
'innodb_show_verbose_locks', '0'
'innodb_sort_buffer_size', '1048576'
'innodb_spin_wait_delay', '6'
'innodb_stats_auto_recalc', 'ON'
'innodb_stats_include_delete_marked', 'OFF'
'innodb_stats_method', 'nulls_equal'
'innodb_stats_modified_counter', '0'
'innodb_stats_on_metadata', 'OFF'
'innodb_stats_persistent', 'ON'
'innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages', '20'
'innodb_stats_sample_pages', '8'
'innodb_stats_traditional', 'ON'
'innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages', '8'
'innodb_status_output', 'OFF'
'innodb_status_output_locks', 'OFF'
'innodb_strict_mode', 'ON'
'innodb_support_xa', 'ON'
'innodb_sync_array_size', '1'
'innodb_sync_spin_loops', '30'
'innodb_table_locks', 'ON'
'innodb_temp_data_file_path', 'ibtmp1:12M:autoextend'
'innodb_thread_concurrency', '0'
'innodb_thread_sleep_delay', '10000'
'innodb_tmpdir', ''
'innodb_track_changed_pages', 'OFF'
'innodb_track_redo_log_now', 'OFF'
'innodb_undo_directory', './'
'innodb_undo_log_truncate', 'OFF'
'innodb_undo_logs', '128'
'innodb_undo_tablespaces', '0'
'innodb_use_atomic_writes', 'ON'
'innodb_use_fallocate', 'OFF'
'innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit', 'OFF'
'innodb_use_mtflush', 'OFF'
'innodb_use_native_aio', 'ON'
'innodb_use_stacktrace', 'OFF'
'innodb_use_trim', 'ON'
'innodb_version', '5.7.26'
'innodb_write_io_threads', '8'
'insert_id', '0'
'interactive_timeout', '28800'
'join_buffer_size', '262144'
'join_buffer_space_limit', '2097152'
'join_cache_level', '2'
'keep_files_on_create', 'OFF'
'key_buffer_size', '20971520'
'key_cache_age_threshold', '300'
'key_cache_block_size', '1024'
'key_cache_division_limit', '100'
'key_cache_file_hash_size', '512'
'key_cache_segments', '0'
'large_files_support', 'ON'
'large_page_size', '0'
'large_pages', 'OFF'
'last_gtid', ''
'last_insert_id', '0'
'lc_messages', 'en_US'
'lc_messages_dir', ''
'lc_time_names', 'en_US'
'license', 'GPL'
'local_infile', 'ON'
'lock_wait_timeout', '86400'
'locked_in_memory', 'OFF'
'log_bin', 'ON'
'log_bin_basename', '/mnt/volume-01-part1/mysql/mysql-bin'
'log_bin_compress', 'OFF'
'log_bin_compress_min_len', '256'
'log_bin_index', '/mnt/volume-01-part1/mysql/mysql-bin.index'
'log_bin_trust_function_creators', 'OFF'
'log_error', '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'
'log_output', 'FILE'
'log_queries_not_using_indexes', 'OFF'
'log_slave_updates', 'OFF'
'log_slow_admin_statements', 'ON'
'log_slow_filter', 'admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,full_join,full_scan,query_cache,query_cache_miss,tmp_table,tmp_table_on_disk'
'log_slow_rate_limit', '1'
'log_slow_slave_statements', 'ON'
'log_slow_verbosity', ''
'log_tc_size', '24576'
'log_warnings', '2'
'long_query_time', '10.000000'
'low_priority_updates', 'OFF'
'lower_case_file_system', 'OFF'
'lower_case_table_names', '0'
'master_verify_checksum', 'OFF'
'max_allowed_packet', '16777216'
'max_binlog_cache_size', '18446744073709547520'
'max_binlog_size', '1073741824'
'max_binlog_stmt_cache_size', '18446744073709547520'
'max_connect_errors', '10'
'max_connections', '100'
'max_delayed_threads', '20'
'max_digest_length', '1024'
'max_error_count', '64'
'max_heap_table_size', '134217728'
'max_insert_delayed_threads', '20'
'max_join_size', '18446744073709551615'
'max_length_for_sort_data', '1024'
'max_long_data_size', '16777216'
'max_prepared_stmt_count', '16382'
'max_recursive_iterations', '4294967295'
'max_relay_log_size', '1073741824'
'max_seeks_for_key', '4294967295'
'max_session_mem_used', '9223372036854775807'
'max_sort_length', '1024'
'max_sp_recursion_depth', '0'
'max_statement_time', '0.000000'
'max_tmp_tables', '32'
'max_user_connections', '0'
'max_write_lock_count', '4294967295'
'metadata_locks_cache_size', '1024'
'metadata_locks_hash_instances', '8'
'min_examined_row_limit', '0'
'mrr_buffer_size', '262144'
'multi_range_count', '256'
'myisam_block_size', '1024'
'myisam_data_pointer_size', '6'
'myisam_max_sort_file_size', '9223372036853727232'
'myisam_mmap_size', '18446744073709551615'
'myisam_recover_options', 'DEFAULT'
'myisam_repair_threads', '1'
'myisam_sort_buffer_size', '134216704'
'myisam_stats_method', 'NULLS_UNEQUAL'
'myisam_use_mmap', 'OFF'
'mysql56_temporal_format', 'ON'
'net_buffer_length', '16384'
'net_read_timeout', '30'
'net_retry_count', '10'
'net_write_timeout', '60'
'old', 'OFF'
'old_alter_table', 'OFF'
'old_mode', ''
'old_passwords', 'OFF'
'open_files_limit', '4233'
'optimizer_prune_level', '1'
'optimizer_search_depth', '62'
'optimizer_selectivity_sampling_limit', '100'
'optimizer_switch', 'index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on'
'optimizer_use_condition_selectivity', '1'
'performance_schema', 'OFF'
'performance_schema_accounts_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_digests_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_events_stages_history_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_events_statements_history_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_events_waits_history_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_hosts_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_cond_classes', '80'
'performance_schema_max_cond_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_digest_length', '1024'
'performance_schema_max_file_classes', '50'
'performance_schema_max_file_handles', '32768'
'performance_schema_max_file_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_mutex_classes', '200'
'performance_schema_max_mutex_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes', '40'
'performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_socket_classes', '10'
'performance_schema_max_socket_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_stage_classes', '150'
'performance_schema_max_statement_classes', '188'
'performance_schema_max_table_handles', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_table_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_max_thread_classes', '50'
'performance_schema_max_thread_instances', '-1'
'performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size', '-1'
'performance_schema_setup_actors_size', '100'
'performance_schema_setup_objects_size', '100'
'performance_schema_users_size', '-1'
'pid_file', '/mnt/volume-01-part1/mysql/dtd-db-01.pid'
'plugin_dir', '/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/'
'plugin_maturity', 'unknown'
'port', '3306'
'preload_buffer_size', '32768'
'profiling', 'OFF'
'profiling_history_size', '15'
'progress_report_time', '5'
'protocol_version', '10'
'proxy_user', ''
'pseudo_slave_mode', 'OFF'
'pseudo_thread_id', '4712'
'query_alloc_block_size', '16384'
'query_cache_limit', '2097152'
'query_cache_min_res_unit', '4096'
'query_cache_size', '134217728'
'query_cache_strip_comments', 'OFF'
'query_cache_type', 'ON'
'query_cache_wlock_invalidate', 'OFF'
'query_prealloc_size', '24576'
'rand_seed1', '289429692'
'rand_seed2', '778761261'
'range_alloc_block_size', '4096'
'read_binlog_speed_limit', '0'
'read_buffer_size', '131072'
'read_only', 'OFF'
'read_rnd_buffer_size', '262144'
'relay_log', ''
'relay_log_basename', ''
'relay_log_index', ''
'relay_log_info_file', 'relay-log.info'
'relay_log_purge', 'ON'
'relay_log_recovery', 'OFF'
'relay_log_space_limit', '0'
'replicate_annotate_row_events', 'ON'
'replicate_do_db', ''
'replicate_do_table', ''
'replicate_events_marked_for_skip', 'REPLICATE'
'replicate_ignore_db', ''
'replicate_ignore_table', ''
'replicate_wild_do_table', ''
'replicate_wild_ignore_table', ''
'report_host', ''
'report_password', ''
'report_port', '3306'
'report_user', ''
'rowid_merge_buff_size', '8388608'
'secure_auth', 'ON'
'secure_file_priv', ''
'server_id', '1'
'session_track_schema', 'ON'
'session_track_state_change', 'OFF'
'session_track_system_variables', ''
'session_track_transaction_info', 'OFF'
'skip_external_locking', 'ON'
'skip_name_resolve', 'ON'
'skip_networking', 'OFF'
'skip_parallel_replication', 'OFF'
'skip_replication', 'OFF'
'skip_show_database', 'OFF'
'slave_compressed_protocol', 'OFF'
'slave_ddl_exec_mode', 'IDEMPOTENT'
'slave_domain_parallel_threads', '0'
'slave_exec_mode', 'STRICT'
'slave_load_tmpdir', '/tmp'
'slave_max_allowed_packet', '1073741824'
'slave_net_timeout', '60'
'slave_parallel_max_queued', '131072'
'slave_parallel_mode', 'conservative'
'slave_parallel_threads', '0'
'slave_parallel_workers', '0'
'slave_run_triggers_for_rbr', 'NO'
'slave_skip_errors', 'OFF'
'slave_sql_verify_checksum', 'ON'
'slave_transaction_retries', '10'
'slave_type_conversions', ''
'slow_launch_time', '2'
'slow_query_log', 'OFF'
'slow_query_log_file', 'dtd-db-01-slow.log'
'socket', '/mnt/volume-01-part1/mysql/mysql.sock'
'sort_buffer_size', '2097152'
'sql_auto_is_null', 'OFF'
'sql_big_selects', 'ON'
'sql_buffer_result', 'OFF'
'sql_log_bin', 'ON'
'sql_log_off', 'OFF'
'sql_mode', 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
'sql_notes', 'ON'
'sql_quote_show_create', 'ON'
'sql_safe_updates', 'OFF'
'sql_select_limit', '18446744073709551615'
'sql_slave_skip_counter', '0'
'sql_warnings', 'OFF'
'ssl_ca', ''
'ssl_capath', ''
'ssl_cert', ''
'ssl_cipher', ''
'ssl_crl', ''
'ssl_crlpath', ''
'ssl_key', ''
'standard_compliant_cte', 'ON'
'storage_engine', 'MyISAM'
'stored_program_cache', '256'
'strict_password_validation', 'ON'
'sync_binlog', '0'
'sync_frm', 'ON'
'sync_master_info', '10000'
'sync_relay_log', '10000'
'sync_relay_log_info', '10000'
'system_time_zone', 'EDT'
'table_definition_cache', '400'
'table_open_cache', '2048'
'table_open_cache_instances', '8'
'thread_cache_size', '12'
'thread_concurrency', '12'
'thread_handling', 'one-thread-per-connection'
'thread_pool_idle_timeout', '60'
'thread_pool_max_threads', '65536'
'thread_pool_oversubscribe', '3'
'thread_pool_prio_kickup_timer', '1000'
'thread_pool_priority', 'auto'
'thread_pool_size', '6'
'thread_pool_stall_limit', '500'
'thread_stack', '196608'
'time_format', '%H:%i:%s'
'time_zone', 'SYSTEM'
'timed_mutexes', 'OFF'
'timestamp', '1562162811.946458'
'tmp_disk_table_size', '18446744073709551615'
'tmp_memory_table_size', '67108864'
'tmp_table_size', '67108864'
'tmpdir', '/tmp'
'transaction_alloc_block_size', '8192'
'transaction_prealloc_size', '4096'
'tx_isolation', 'REPEATABLE-READ'
'tx_read_only', 'OFF'
'unique_checks', 'ON'
'updatable_views_with_limit', 'YES'
'use_stat_tables', 'NEVER'
'userstat', 'OFF'
'version', '10.2.25-MariaDB-log'
'version_comment', 'MariaDB Server'
'version_compile_machine', 'x86_64'
'version_compile_os', 'Linux'
'version_malloc_library', 'system'
'version_ssl_library', 'OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017'
'wait_timeout', '28800'
'warning_count', '0'
'wsrep_osu_method', 'TOI'
'wsrep_auto_increment_control', 'ON'
'wsrep_causal_reads', 'OFF'
'wsrep_certification_rules', 'strict'
'wsrep_certify_nonpk', 'ON'
'wsrep_cluster_address', ''
'wsrep_cluster_name', 'my_wsrep_cluster'
'wsrep_convert_lock_to_trx', 'OFF'
'wsrep_data_home_dir', '/mnt/volume-01-part1/mysql/'
'wsrep_dbug_option', ''
'wsrep_debug', 'OFF'
'wsrep_desync', 'OFF'
'wsrep_dirty_reads', 'OFF'
'wsrep_drupal_282555_workaround', 'OFF'
'wsrep_forced_binlog_format', 'NONE'
'wsrep_gtid_domain_id', '0'
'wsrep_gtid_mode', 'OFF'
'wsrep_load_data_splitting', 'ON'
'wsrep_log_conflicts', 'OFF'
'wsrep_max_ws_rows', '0'
'wsrep_max_ws_size', '2147483647'
'wsrep_mysql_replication_bundle', '0'
'wsrep_node_address', ''
'wsrep_node_incoming_address', 'AUTO'
'wsrep_node_name', 'dtd-db-01'
'wsrep_notify_cmd', ''
'wsrep_on', 'OFF'
'wsrep_patch_version', 'wsrep_25.24'
'wsrep_provider', 'none'
'wsrep_provider_options', ''
'wsrep_recover', 'OFF'
'wsrep_reject_queries', 'NONE'
'wsrep_replicate_myisam', 'OFF'
'wsrep_restart_slave', 'OFF'
'wsrep_retry_autocommit', '1'
'wsrep_slave_fk_checks', 'ON'
'wsrep_slave_uk_checks', 'OFF'
'wsrep_slave_threads', '1'
'wsrep_sst_auth', ''
'wsrep_sst_donor', ''
'wsrep_sst_donor_rejects_queries', 'OFF'
'wsrep_sst_method', 'rsync'
'wsrep_sst_receive_address', 'AUTO'
'wsrep_start_position', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1'
'wsrep_sync_wait', '0'
```

**EDIT:**
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
https://pastebin.com/3iXGGZ6N

(sorry, too long for SO)

Comment: Looking at the error with `innodb_table_stats` -- Did you upgrade recently?  But failed to run `mysql_upgrade`?

Comment: We fixed that error by manually recreating the table.

Comment: We haven't rebooted the server yet and running mysql_upgrade now gives errors like : ERROR 1932 (42S02) at line 595: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist in engine
ERROR 1243 (HY000) at line 596: Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE
ERROR 1932 (42S02) at line 603: Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: Hmmm...  What version did you upgrade _from_ and _to_?

Comment: Just a yum update, not a major version. I'm not sure of the previous version.

Comment: Currently MariaDB-10.2.25.  Have you always used MariaDB?  Or was it MySQL at some point?

Comment: Fresh install as MariaDB 10. Never MySQL.

Comment: Could you also provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`

Comment: Added as a edit in Pastebin https://pastebin.com/3iXGGZ6N

Comment: Do you have SSD, NVME or rotating HDD?  Please post from LX command prompt the TEXT results of iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, and ulimit -a for Open Files capacity.

Comment: I have recreated both `innodb_table_stats` and `innodb_index_stats` an then ran `mysql_upgrade` successfully (it previously failed). Server has been stable since, but I am monitoring through a busy time of day and will update if the fix is successful.

Comment: You are making progress, now that upgrade was successful. Do you have SSD, NVME or rotating HDD? Please post from LX command prompt the TEXT results of iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device, and ulimit -a for Open Files capacity. Thanks

Comment: This is apparently a confirmed bug: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15178

Comment: What is result of SELECT @@binlog_cache_size?  Rick James suggested SET GLOBAL binlog_cache_size=1*1024*1024;  for 1M rather than 30M.  This is a per connection value that was extremely large when you posted SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  The default of 32768 works well for MOST INSTANCES.  Please view profile, Network profile for contact info and get in touch.  We still would like to know if you have rotating HDD, SSD or NVME for data storage.

Comment: `SELECT @@binlog_cache_size` = 1048576. SSD Drive. Had set that as a first attempt. Server has since crashed twice.

Answer (score 1):

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.2.25-MariaDB-log
- 16 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 03:04:23; Please rerun SHOW GLOBAL STATUS after several hours.
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

binlog_cache_size is dangerously high -- change from 30M to 1M

Suggest using the slowlog; see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

**Details and other observations:**

`( binlog_cache_size * max_connections / _ram ) = 30M * 100 / 16384M = 18.3%` -- RAM used for caching transactions on the way to the binlog.
-- Decrease binlog_cache_size and/or max_connections

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth * innodb_page_cleaners ) = 512 * 4 = 2,048` -- Amount of work for page cleaners every second.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixable by lowering lru_scan_depth: Consider 1000 / innodb_page_cleaners

`( innodb_page_cleaners / innodb_buffer_pool_instances ) = 4 / 6 = 0.667` -- innodb_page_cleaners
-- Recommend setting innodb_page_cleaners to innodb_buffer_pool_instances

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 181,655 / 737235 = 24.6%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size is bigger than necessary?

`( Innodb_pages_written / Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests ) = 33,499 / 70858 = 47.3%` -- Write requests that had to hit disk
-- Check innodb_buffer_pool_size

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 11,063 / 60 * 3072M / 24557056 = 24,186` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size. (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( default_tmp_storage_engine ) = default_tmp_storage_engine =`

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor.

`( sync_binlog ) = 0` -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_populate ) = OFF = 0` -- NUMA control

`( default_storage_engine ) = default_storage_engine = MyISAM`
-- MyISAM is deprecated and mostly less desirable than InnoDB

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile = ON is a potential security issue

`( query_cache_size ) = 128M` -- Size of QC
-- Too small = not of much use. Too large = too much overhead. Recommend either 0 or no more than 50M.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables ) = 15,777 / 11063 = 1.4 /sec` -- Frequency of creating *disk* "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs
-- increase tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size.
Check the rules for temp tables on when MEMORY is used instead of MyISAM. Perhaps minor schema or query changes can avoid MyISAM.
Better indexes and reformulation of queries are more likely to help.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Questions ) = 15,777 / 104672 = 15.1%` -- Pct of queries that needed on-disk tmp table.
-- Better indexes / No blobs / etc.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Created_tmp_tables ) = 15,777 / 33066 = 47.7%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Maybe increase tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size; improve indexes; avoid blobs, etc.

`( Select_full_join / Com_select ) = 6,864 / 55356 = 12.4%` -- % of selects that are indexless join
-- Add suitable index(es) to tables used in JOINs.

`( Select_scan ) = 17,137 / 11063 = 1.5 /sec` -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 17,137 / 55356 = 31.0%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED. ROW is preferred; it may become the default.

`( expire_logs_days ) = 3` -- How soon to automatically purge binlog (after this many days)
-- Too large (or zero) = consumes disk space; too small = need to respond quickly to network/machine crash.
(Not relevant if log_bin = OFF)

`( wsrep_on ) = wsrep_on = OFF` -- Galera: Turn on Replication
-- Why is it OFF?

`( innodb_autoinc_lock_mode ) = 1` -- Galera: desires 2 -- 2 = "interleaved"; 1 = "consecutive" is typical; 0 = "traditional".

`( wsrep_log_conflicts ) = wsrep_log_conflicts = OFF` -- If you get deadlock conflicts during COMMIT, this flag can be helpful.

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( Subquery_cache_hit / ( Subquery_cache_hit + Subquery_cache_miss ) ) = 10 / ( 10 + 1074 ) = 0.92%` -- Subquery cache hit rate
-- Consider SET optimizer_switch='subquery_cache=off';

**Abnormally small:**

```
Acl_users = 5
Com_show_fields = 0
Com_show_tables = 0
Handler_read_rnd_next / Handler_read_rnd = 6.13
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed = 2.12
Key_blocks_used = 0
Key_read_requests = 0
Table_locks_immediate = 6.5 /HR
eq_range_index_dive_limit = 0   (always use index dives)
innodb_log_block_size = 0  (Deprecated as of MariaDB 10.2.6)
innodb_max_bitmap_file_size = 0
innodb_max_changed_pages = 0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups = 0
innodb_sched_priority_cleaner = 0
innodb_show_locks_held = 0
lock_wait_timeout = 86,400
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
((query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache) / query_cache_min_res_unit = 6.67
(query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache = 27,332
Aria_pagecache_writes = 11 /sec
Com_create_temporary_table = 0.65 /HR
Com_load = 0.65 /HR
Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data = 816674 /sec
Qcache_total_blocks * query_cache_min_res_unit / Qcache_queries_in_cache = 157,586
binlog_cache_size = 3.15e+7
group_concat_max_len = 1.05e+6
innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions = 8
innodb_background_scrub_data_check_interval = 0.33 /sec
innodb_background_scrub_data_interval = 55 /sec
max_relay_log_size = 1024MB
thread_concurrency = 12
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
binlog_annotate_row_events = ON
ft_boolean_syntax = + -><()~*:\"\"&
innodb_corrupt_table_action = deprecated
innodb_defragment = ON
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
innodb_locking_fake_changes = OFF
innodb_use_atomic_writes = ON
innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit = OFF
innodb_use_trim = ON
log_slow_admin_statements = ON
log_slow_slave_statements = ON
myisam_stats_method = NULLS_UNEQUAL
opt_s__engine_condition_pushdown = off
opt_s__orderby_uses_equalities = on
replicate_annotate_row_events = ON
session_track_system_variables =
```

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second=RPS - Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=256  # from 12 for the minimum suggested in REFMAN for 10.nn.nn MariaDB
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to enable higher SSD IOPS
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 512 to reduce CPU cycles used for function
read_buffer_size=512K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 117,695
read_rnd_buffer_size=192K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_nxt RPS of 4,114
```

Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned at my profile, Network profile and have available free Utility Scripts to improve your performance and additional suggestions.

Comment: @DeweyOx Have you had opportunity to try these suggestions? Any feedback positive or negative?

Comment: @DeweyOx  Suggestions attempted?  Feedback, positive or negative?

Comment: @deweyox       Any feedback on your use of Suggestions on Jul 6, 19?  Upvote, Downvote and/or Accept?